# a real convergent sequence has a unique limit point

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that a real convergent sequence has a unique limit point viz. the limit of the sequene?

I've used the result several times but I don't know how to prove it!

Please help me!

Comment: How do you define convergent? One possible *definition* is that a series is convergent if it has exactly one limit point...

Comment: suppose it converged to 2 different limits, what would their difference be?

Comment: @fgp: $x_n\to l\iff\text{for }\epsilon>0~\exists~k\in\mathbb N,\text{ such that }|x_n-l|<\epsilon~\forall~n\ge k.$

Comment: @Arjang: I'm not looking for the proof of the existence of unique limit rather the existence of unique limit point when limit exists.

Comment: @fgp : no need for that, besides that would be putting too much into a definition, definitions are suppose to have least amount of constraints in them and most other things are suppose to follow from the definitin not defined by it.

Comment: @SritiMallick : can you write  what you just said in the form what implies what please? I read what you said few times but I am still confused. +1 for confusing me

Comment: @Arjang Huh? I haven't said that it's the *only* definition, but it's certainly a *possible* definition. The thing is, real analysis can be developed in a lot of different ways, so without stating the definitions, a question like this is hard to answer, because for *some* definitions the theorem may be trivial, while for others it involve some work. If you define $\lim x_n := \limsup x_n = \liminf x_n$ *if* the two coincide, then the OP's question is trivial...

Comment: @SritiMallick 'kay, now one would also need your definition of limit point...

Comment: @fgp : sorry, didn't mean to imply you said "only definition", 20 years since I did the analysis course, I am confusing myself.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Suppose that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ has two different limits $l_1$ and $l_2$. There exists a number $\varepsilon>0$ such that $2\varepsilon<|l_1-l_2|$. Then $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods of the points $l_1$ and $l_2$ are disjoint. Therefore, for sufficiently large $n$ we have that ...

Answer (score 3):

Assume to the contrary that the sequence $\{X_n\}$ has two limit points, say $a$ and $b$. Then we have $|a-X_n| < ε$  for $n\ge N_1$ and $|b-X_n| < ε$ for $n\ge N_2$. Let $ε*= (a-b)/4$. 
Then we have

$$\begin{aligned}
               |a-b| &= |a-b+Xn-Xn|\\
                     &= |(a-Xn)+(-b+Xn)|\\
                     &\le|(a-Xn)|+|(b-Xn)|\\
                     &\le 2ε
                      = 2(a-b)/4\\
                      &= (a-b)/2,
\end{aligned}$$

which is not correct for our $ε$. Thus, we showed one $ε$, which is already enough, that contradicts the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that limit points are defined as in Section $6.4$ of the book Analysis $1$ by the author Terence Tao. We assume that the sequence of real numbers $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to the real number $c$. Then we have to show that $c$ is the unique limit point of the sequence. First, we shall show that $c$ is indeed a limit point. By the definition of convergence we have
$$\forall\epsilon > 0\:\exists N_{\epsilon}\geq m\:\text{s.t.}\:\forall n\geq N_{\epsilon}\:|a_{n}-c|\leq\epsilon$$
We need to prove that $\forall\epsilon >0\:\forall N\geq m\:\exists n\geq N\:\text{s.t.}\:|a_{n}-c|\leq\epsilon$. Fix $\epsilon$ and $N$. If $N\leq N_{\epsilon}$ then we could pick and $n\geq N_{\epsilon}$. If $N>N_{\epsilon}$ then picking any $n\geq N > N_{\epsilon}$ would suffice.

Now, we shall prove that $c$ is the unique limit point. Let us assume for the sake of contradiction that $\exists$ a limit point $c'\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c'\neq c$. Since the sequence converges to $c$, $\forall\epsilon > 0\:\exists M_{\epsilon}\geq m$ such that $\forall n\geq M_{\epsilon}$ we have $|a_{n}-c|\leq \epsilon/2$. Further, since $c'$ is a limit point, $\forall\epsilon > 0$ and $\forall N\geq m\:\exists k_{N}\geq N$ such that $|a_{k_{N}}-c'|\leq \epsilon/2$. In particular, $|a_{k_{M_{\epsilon}}}-c'|\leq \epsilon/2$ and $|a_{k_{M_{\epsilon}}}-c|\leq \epsilon/2$. Using the triangle inequality we get $\forall\epsilon > 0\: |c-c'|\leq\epsilon\implies |c-c'| = 0\implies c = c'$ which contradicts the assumption.